# WordPress how to automatically resize uploading all images and delete original of image on server?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, resize, scaling

I want to all images that will be stored on server to be maximum 900px width.

Example:
User uploads image with 3500px by 3500px, i need it auto resize for 900px and then delete original 3500px image from server. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate different sizes of images, you can add custom thumbnails that will be created when an image is uploaded. You can achieve this with a couple of lines of code in functions.php:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/

I'm not sure deleting the original is possible, as it's linked with the different thumbnails that are generated. A couple of tweaks in your template do however ensure the original isn't used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found great plugin that makes what i want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/